# Alert dialogue title and message are not shown

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

i created alert dialogue but title and message are not shown here is my code for alert dialogue

```
holder.add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder;
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context, android.R.style.Theme_Material_Dialog_Alert);
            } else {
                builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            }
            builder.setTitle("Alert");
            builder.setMessage("Are you sure")
                    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            // User cancelled the dialog
                        }
                    });
            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();
        }
    });
```

this is the screenshot of it [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `context`, try to use `ActivityName.this`.

Answer (score 4):

You have to pass theme as well in AlertBuilder.

```
AlertDialog.Builder myAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext(), R.style.AppCompatAlertDialogStyle);
deleteAlert.setTitle(title);
deleteAlert.setMessage(message);
deleteAlert.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, clickListener);
deleteAlert.setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, clickListener);
deleteAlert.show();
```

No need to call the create() method if you have called show(). Because internally the show() method calls create().

Note:
I can clearly say the issue from my experience. I missed to pass theme.

```
R.style.AppCompatAlertDialogStyle
```

**DOES NOT WORK:**

```
AlertDialog.Builder myAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
```

**WORKS SUCCESFULLY:**

```
AlertDialog.Builder myAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext(),  R.style.AppCompatAlertDialogStyle);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is causing it, but for start I'm pretty sure you don't need to call `builder.create()` then `dialog.show()` separately.

Call directly `builder.show()` and let the Alert Dialog Builder handle its creation and display. If you really need the `dialog` instance, get it from the result of the `builder.show()`.

About the lack of texts, maybe you are overriding some style, have you checked if the texts are simply White colored and because of that are "invisible"?

Comment: Can you post your styles sources for the `Theme_Material_Dialog_Alert` ?